# Does ioremap require a future page fault

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

Ioremap is done in kernel mode.
Does ioremap create an entry in pagetables during
 the call of ioremap or when the address is accessed ?

Comment: please state the reason for -1. If you know the answer help

Answer (score 2):

For ioremap, the page tables are updated immediately. Since the function is intended to map physical "I/O" addresses into kernel virtual address space, there would be no point in setting up page table entries to cause a page fault. In essence, a page fault supports the dynamic substitution of one page of physical memory for another. But by definition, I/O space is not substitutable.

For example, one common use of ioremap is to allow a kernel module to access register space on an add-on card or other peripheral. In order to perform operations on the card, the kernel code must obtain a virtual address that refers to the physical bus address corresponding to the card's register area. ioremap causes the allocation of virtual space, and the establishment of a mapping from that virtual range to the card space. It wouldn't make sense to "swap" the underlying physical page: that page isn't a real memory page, it has special functions that can't be duplicated by any other physical memory.

Comment: Your point is valid for desktop based systems, but for embedded systems where there is no swapping ?

Comment: I don't see the relevance of embedded vs desktop with respect to the ioremap behavior. It still wouldn't make sense to have a page fault for I/O space.